# ArrayList objects

Tags: java

Need some inputs:

Lets say i have N `ArrayList` and in each i am adding foo() object.

```
Foo foo = new Foo()

A.add(foo);

B.add(foo);

N.add(foo);
```

Now modification done on any one `foo()` object will reflect in all the other arraylist?

1. If YES WHY? and
2. whether this behaviour can also be achieved using any other collection like Vector etc...?
3. IF i make foo as null will it reflect in all arraylist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Yes, because all lists only contain a reference to the same objects
2. Yes, all collections work like that
3. No, because you can only set a reference to null, and each list has a copy of the reference.

Comment: could you elaborate on 'No' in 3?

Comment: @aviad: A B and N each contain a copy of the reference foo, and all of them refer to the same object. Setting foo to null will not have any effect on the copies.

Comment: I thought that the object itself will be nullified (foo=null) then all the collections refer to null. do I miss something?

Comment: @aviad: Yes, you simply thought wrong. foo = null has no effect whatsoever on the object itself (Objects cannot be null), it only removes the reference and if there is no other reference the object will eventually be picked up by the garbage collector.

Comment: Thanks Michael, MJM and aviad for clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

Any implementation of `Collection API` such as `ArrayList` or `Vector` hold reference to an object in heap memory so when you would get an index of a `List` by `get(index)` method, you achive reference to object so:

1. Yes, if get an index of list by `get(index)` method and then change the stat of the achieved object, changes stay in memory.
2. Yes,All `Collection API` have this behavior.
3. No,When achieve to a index of list, act is: "You achieve a copy of reference to object" and when set it to null, list instance don't any change.